# Cannot remove padding from Android Material slider

Tags: android, slider, padding

I've created a slider and I want to remove the padding. It seem it's not possible. I know there is some padding necessary for the thump, but I'd like to take care of the padding myself.

```
        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp" />
```

Even with setting padding to 0 it still shows some padding. It seems the padding parameter is ignored. It also seems the thumb diameter is not taken into account for the padding.

[image taken from layout inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vblmo.png)

How can I set the padding? What if I want a real big thumb diameter?

Comment: Do you have a solution for this? I think the padding is based on the thumb radius

Answer (score 8):

If you add `<dimen name="mtrl_slider_track_side_padding">0dp</dimen>` in your dimens.xml, the paddings is gone, Is not the ideal solution but maybe works for you.

Answer (score 3):

all dimensions are [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/res/values/dimens.xml)

you can override all of them in your project dimens.xml

Answer (score 1):

This property is named "trackSidePadding" in BaseSlider which is the parent of the Slider class

You can use java reflection to change it:

kotlin:

```
val field: Field = slider.javaClass.superclass.getDeclaredField("trackSidePadding")

field.isAccessible = true

field.set(slider, 'YOUR INT VALUE')
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the height of the Material Slider widget, you can add `<dimen name="mtrl_slider_widget_height">30dp</dimen>` in your dimens.xml.

By default, the height of the Material Slider widget is `48dp`. Adjusting this dimension will change the height accordingly.

If you also want to remove the side padding of the slider track, you can add `<dimen name="mtrl_slider_track_side_padding">0dp</dimen>` in dimens.xml.

[Here are the all dimensions](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/slider/res/values/dimens.xml)

[image: Material Slider widget]